# Highstock on load graph displays just one point

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, highcharts

I am drawing a spline graph and getting a problem where in graph shows only one point on load of graph.On the other hand if I click on range selector or horizontal scroll of graph , it displays all points of graph correctly.

I tried with different data also and graph displays correctly.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hpRCm/) to see that

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
chart: {
  renderTo: 'container',
  defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
  zoomType: 'x'
}});
```

I did try to understand the data pattern and googled to find if there is any issue with highstock but no avail.

[image]

Comment: Your fiddle reports `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : (index:)27` in console. I tried the same code on my system (copy&paste to a file), there is no error and everything seems ok. All points are shown after page load. Tested with Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @Anto..I verified the fiddle in multiple machine and tested in chrome and FF ..output is same as shown above in image.

Comment: I believe you. I saw the same in fiddle. Strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your graph doesn't get the initial range status correctly, as you may notice that 'All' range button is disabled when first load.

Declare a pre-selected option: `selected:0` in **rangeSelector** would help (http://jsfiddle.net/MS63L/)

```
   rangeSelector: {
          selected:0, 
          buttons: [
             .... rest part are same as your original code
```

You can change the integer according to your need: 0 select '5m', 1 select '15m', 2 select 'All'. As this attribute means **The index of the button to appear pre-selected.**

**See also**: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector.selected

Comment: Paul Lo....Thanks a lot for perfect solution....This solved my problem. I am still wondering why for some other data it shows graph perfectly without event setting property 'selected'.